# media запросы в css

Tags: css

В верстке новичок. Правильно ли я понимаю что в media запросах max-width означает ширину самого монитора устройства, а min-width порог сжатия окна браузера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max-width это порог "разжатия" окна браузера, max-width тоже самое что и min-width - только наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` это макимальная ширина экрана, т.е. свойства применяются для всего что ниже этого разрешения и до следующего `max-width` которые его перечеркнут на меньшем диапазоне. С `min-width` наоборот, это минимальная ширина экрана и его перечеркивают свойства выше этого разрешения экранов